# How to perform a crosstab based on data in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

So looking at [an official example](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/tablefunc.html):

```
CREATE TABLE ct(id SERIAL, rowid TEXT, attribute TEXT, value TEXT);
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test1','att1','val1');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test1','att2','val2');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test1','att3','val3');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test1','att4','val4');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test2','att1','val5');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test2','att2','val6');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test2','att3','val7');
INSERT INTO ct(rowid, attribute, value) VALUES('test2','att4','val8');

SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'select rowid, attribute, value
   from ct
   where attribute = ''att2'' or attribute = ''att3''
   order by 1,2')
AS ct(row_name text, category_1 text, category_2 text, category_3 text);
```

They literally state columns count. They produce:

```
 row_name | category_1 | category_2 | category_3
----------+------------+------------+------------
 test1    | val2       | val3       |
 test2    | val6       | val7       |
```

How to make columns count based on total attribute to get something line this:

```
 row_name | att1       | att2       | att3       | attr4
----------+------------+------------+---------------------
 test1    | val1       | val2       | val3       | val4
 test2    | val5       | val6       | val7       | val8
```

Composed from pure table data and not from predefined constant column count?

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Filter aggregation is usually way easier to work with than the convoluted `crosstab()` function. Or maybe just aggregate into a JSON value